# Intuition on homotopy group

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I just started learning some algebraic topology and trying to make sense of the following identity, 
$$
\pi_m(S^n) = \begin{cases}
\mathbb{Z} , & m = n \\
0 , & m < n \, .
\end{cases}
$$
I think of $\pi_1(S^1) = \mathbb{Z}$ in the following way: looping/ winding around a circle twice or once are not equivalent. Or I can not "bend, stretch, shrink" a loop with "winding" = 1 to "winding" = 2 on a circle. Hence $\mathbb{Z}$ is nothing but the winding numbers. First of all is this way of thinking correct? Second, I can not make sense of why should $\pi_1(S^2)$ vanish ?

Comment: The intuition behind $\pi_1(S^2)=0$ is that every loop on a sphere can be continuously contracted to a point.

Comment: Ultimately, the best way to understand a statement like this is to understand its proof.  You can try to get some sort of intuition, but unless you understand how that intuition translates into a proof, there's not much you can do with it.

Comment: Chapter 4 of Allen Hatchers book 'Algebraic Topology' is a great place to start!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that way of thinking is correct. When you learn the proof of this fact from the point of view of covering space theory you will see how to make this intuition precise.

For your second question, this is actually a non-trivial theorem. The subtle point is that it is possible for a continuous map from $S^1$ to $S^2$ to be surjective. However, it is always possible to make a homotopy that makes a surjective $f: S^1 \to S^2$ no longer surjective, essentially because $S^1$ is one-dimensional so you can pick a point and push the image off bit by bit (you pick a neighborhood of this point that misses your basepoint, then there is a linear homotopy to the boundary circle that you can write down - this is probably best explained with a picture, not words). Once you have a map $f: S^1 \to S^2$ which is not surjective, it will factor through $R^2$ (since the sphere without a point is homeomorphic to $R^2$ via the stereographic projection), and now you can use the contractictibility of $R^2$ to conclude that any such loop was nullhomotopic.

Comment: I don't really see what compactness has to do with being able to homotope $f$ to not be surjective.  It has much more to do with the fact that $S^1$ is one-dimensional (and there are various different ways one can make this rigorous).

Comment: @EricWofsey You make a good point, one dimensionality is more important here. I thought about the proof again and your really do not need compactness. Thanks, I'll update my response.

Comment: Thanks @AreaMan, can you please provide any reference where I can find proof via covering space theory. Also since you mentioned contractibility, It just occurred to me will the fundamental group for a punctured sphere be $\mathbb{Z}$ again ?

Comment: @JonSnow I think I learned this from Lee's Topological manifolds.  The punctured sphere is contractible, so it has the homotopy type of a point, meaning that it has trivial fundamental group. The *twice* punctured sphere has the homotopy type of the punctured plane, which has the homotopy type of a circle, so it has fundamental group Z.

Comment: Perhaps you had in mind not a punctured sphere, which is $\cong \mathbb{R}^2$, but a punctured disk, with a point removed from its interior. *That* is homotopic to $S^1$.